# Redis is not saving data in the docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis

I have this docker-compose.yml file code:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    image: 'redis:latest'
    environment:
      X_REDIS_PORT: ${REDIS_PORT}
    ports:
      - ${REDIS_PORT}:${REDIS_PORT}
    volumes:
      - redis:/data

    networks:
      app_network:
            external: true
            driver: bridge
    volumes:
      postgres:
      pgadmin:
      supertoken:
      redis:
```

I want to save the cached data inside of the redis container but it is not getting saved in the container instead it gets saved on my local machine.
How to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

inspect your volume,

```
docker volume inspect redis
```

the mountpoint is /var/lib/docker/volumes/, check the redis volumes data.

I use folder,there is a demo in my [github repo](https://github.com/FX-Max/docker-install-everything/blob/master/redis/docker-compose.yml),

```
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```